# @Observable class member not triggering UI update

Tags: swiftui

Minimal reproducible example using the `@Observable` macro is included below.  Tried as both an environment and a bindable var in the view. Renders as expected, and clicking on the rectangles prints out:

```
from environment zoo false
from environment zoo true
from bindable false
from environment false
from bindable true
from environment true
from environment false
from environment true
from environment false
from bindable false
from bindable true
from bindable false
...
```

but the colors do not update.  Adding `let _ = Self._printChanges()` in the body causes `ContentView: @self, @identity, _fooWrapper changed.` to be printed once on appear and no more (when clicking).

What is wrong with this code and how to fix it?

```swift
// FooApp.swift
import SwiftUI

class Bar {
  var selected: Bool
  init() { self.selected = false }
}

protocol FooProtocol {
  var bar: Bar { get set }
}

@Observable
class FooWrapper {
  var foo: any FooProtocol
  init(foo: some FooProtocol) { self.foo = foo }
}

class Foo {
  var bar: Bar
  init() { self.bar = .init() }
}
extension Foo: FooProtocol {}

// Fully concrete, no existentials.
@Observable
class ZooWrapper {
  var foo: Foo
  init() { self.foo = Foo() }
}

@main
struct FooApp: App {
  @State private var foo = FooWrapper(foo: Foo())
  @State private var zoo = ZooWrapper()

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView().environment(foo)
    }
  }
}
```

and the view

```
// ContentView.swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @Environment(FooWrapper.self) private var fooWrapper
  
  var body: some View {
    @Bindable var fooWrapper1 = FooWrapper(foo: Foo())

    HStack {
      Rectangle()
        .fill(zooWrapper.foo.bar.selected ? Color.green : .blue)
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        .onTapGesture {
          var bar = zooWrapper.foo.bar
          print("from environment zoo \(bar.selected)")
          bar.selected.toggle()
        }
      Rectangle()
        .fill(fooWrapper.foo.bar.selected ? Color.purple : .yellow)
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        .onTapGesture {
          var bar = fooWrapper.foo.bar
          print("from environment \(bar.selected)")
          bar.selected.toggle()
        }
      Rectangle()
        .fill(fooWrapper1.foo.bar.selected ? Color.mint : .red)
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        .onTapGesture {
          var bar = fooWrapper1.foo.bar
          print("from bindable \(bar.selected)")
          bar.selected.toggle()
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Property wrappers belong at struct level but existentials don’t actually conform to their protocol you probably need a concrete Observable

Comment: The existential doesn't seem to matter (I updated the example with a fully concrete one which does not work either).  Not sure what you mean about the property wrappers at struct level?  If you're referring to the Bindable the documentaion explicitly states that it can be anywhere, incl. as a local var: "You can use the Bindable property wrapper on properties and variables to an Observable object. This includes global variables, properties that exists outside of SwiftUI types, or even local variables. For example, you can create a Bindable variable within a view’s body:"

Comment: Make foo and bar observable too or a struct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@Observable` macro expands to add special getters and setters to the properties. It does not do anything to other classes.

```
var foo: any FooProtocol
```

eventually becomes

```
var foo: any FooProtocol
{
    @storageRestrictions(initializes: _foo)
    init(initialValue) {
      _foo = initialValue
    }

    get {
      access(keyPath: \.foo)
      return _foo
    }

    set {
      withMutation(keyPath: \.foo) {
        _foo = newValue
      }
    }
}
```

Note that `_foo` is also a property generated by the macro.

As you can see, changes can only be observed if you call the setter of `foo`.

`bar.selected.toggle()`, or `fooWrapper.foo.bar.selected.toggle()` for that matter, does not call the setter of `fooWrapper.foo`. It just calls the setter for `selected`.

If `Foo` and `Bar` are both structs, then setting `selected` *would* call the setter for `foo`, because of value semantics.

If you don't want to make `Foo` and `Bar` structs, you can also make `Bar` observable:

```
@Observable
class Bar {
  var selected: Bool
  init() { self.selected = false }
}
```

Then `selected` will get "special setters", and the view will be able to observe the changes.

As for `fooWrapper1`, I'm not sure why you would think that would ever work. You declared it in `body`, so a new `FooWrapper` would be created every time `body` is evaluated, and `selected` is always initialised to false.

Just put it outside the `body`, without any property wrappers:

```
var fooWrapper1 = FooWrapper(foo: Foo())
var body: some View {
    ...
}
```

`@Bindable` is for when you want a `Binding` for `selected` inside `body`,

```
@Bindable var fooWrapperBindable = fooWrapper1
// now $fooWrapperBindable.selected is a Binding<Bool>
```

Notice that I am assigning the existing `fooWrapper1`, not a new instance.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, making Bar observable did the trick.